# Can't access resources from same directory in several projects with Class.getResource in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, getresource

I use maven to create a runnable jar from multiple projects :

Project A (contains the Main class):
    `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/a.txt`

Project B (depends on Project A):
    `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/b.txt`

Runnable.jar (create with mvn):
    `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/a.txt`,`/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/b.txt`

In the Main class I use `Class.class.getResource` to get the content of a.txt and b.txt.
When I do `java -jar Runnable.jar`, I can access to a.txt and b.txt. But if I run it from Eclipse, I can only access to a.txt . Is it possible to get it right?  I'd like to change resources content when the application is running and get the result without recompiling.

The Run configuration :
[MAIN] => Project : Poject B, Main class : Main 
[ClassPath] => UserEntry : Project A, Project B

NB : If I change the order of the UserEntry, I can access to b.txt but not a.txt.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Project B needs to be added to Project A's `Java Build Path`. Open up project A's Properties dialog and do so.

Comment: On which tab?

*getting sick and tired of this length requirement on comments*

Comment: I'm sorry i change the content of my question rather than use the comment to make the question more accurate. I don't know if this is the usage or I have to answer my own question to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I've created a linked resource folder  in project B (B/src/main/resources-a) which refers to the resources directory of project A (A/src/main/resources). I set the new linked folder as a source directory. Now it works and I can see the resources contained in the Project A in the target/classes folder of Project B. It's exactly what I expected but if I'd like 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' automaticaly configure .project and .classpath files?